# hide mouse pointer for second monitor as touch panel for device

Tags: touch-screen

we are making a device as an expert system. we use Ubuntu 18.04 minimal as OS. the device has 2 screen, first screen is a display screen for operator and second screen is a touch screen as a touch panel for getting instruction from operator.
so when i connect touch panel, mouse pointer appear at the touch point.
i want to hide mouse pointer for touch panel.
i tried **unclutter** for this problem. it seems unclutter has problem with ubuntu minimal and mouse pointer start to blink after activating unclutter.

how do i config mouse and touch panel to, mouse pointer does not appear when touch screen has touched?

for more information :

I use **ORG** for display server and **LightDM** as display manager and **OpenBox** as windows manager.

Comment: You say one screen is for the operator, and one for the user. It seems that there are two separate activities, and therefore should be different user-sessions. Probably logged in as different users.

Comment: No it is my fault. User and operator are the one person.

Comment: *Something* needs to be in control of this. Usually it's the window manager (WM), often as part of the desktop. I don't know which WM Ubuntu minimal uses, so find out which one you have installed, find out if you can configure it to hide the mouse pointer on the second screen, or switch to a different WM where you can do this (switching should be still possible in Ubuntu). The blinking is likely unclutter fighting with some other app (prime candidate is the WM) over the mouse pointer.

Comment: thanks for your advice.
I installed **OpenBox** for wm.